# Add single row to xlsx keep formatting

Tags: r, xlsx

I would like to use R to append an xlsx file with a single row 3 columns wide.  The xlsx file has some formatting I don't want to lose.  The append option in the `xlsx` package's `read.xlsx` does not append in the same way `read.table` does.  From what I read it is for appending sheets.

```
library(xlsx)
## I have an xlsx similar to this but with highlighting and such
write.xlsx(mtcars[1:3, 1:3], "test.xlsx", row.names=FALSE)

## Row I want to append
mtcars[4, 1:3]
```

How can I add this row to the xlsx file without ruining the formatting (highlights etc.).  I'm currently trying to use the `xlsx` package to do this but am not wed to its use.

Error with append which is expected because `append` works on sheets:

```
> write.xlsx(mtcars[4, 1:3], "test.xlsx", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
Error in .jcall(wb, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;", "createSheet",  : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution using `appendWorksheet` from `XLConnect` package:

```
library(XLConnect)
# mtcars xlsx file from demoFiles subfolder of package XLConnect
demoExcelFile <- system.file("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx", package = "XLConnect")
wb <- loadWorkbook(demoExcelFile)
appendWorksheet(wb, mtcars, sheet = "mtcars")
saveWorkbook(wb,demoExcelFile)
```